# How to set 9 am to 5 pm Mon-Fri on google calendar? i.e. repeat out-of-office

Tags: google-calendar

I know it is possible to set working hours on google calendar but I would like to have as OoO automatic replied anything beyond 9-5 from Mon-Fri.